# Can VirtualBox shared folders be mounted as removable storage devices?

Tags: virtualbox

Is it possible to mount shared folders in a Windows 7 guest as removable storage drives rather than network locations? Host is Xubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### No.

The [VirtualBox manual](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#sharedfolders) states that shared folders under Windows guests only appear as network shares. The [source code](https://www.virtualbox.org/browser/vbox/trunk/src/VBox/Additions/WINNT/SharedFolders) also indicates that shared folders are only implemented as network shares.